# Database query requires quotation marks around date

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I'm trying to query my database using the following:

```
connection.Query(@"SELECT timestamp FROM hdd_local_data_v1_2 WHERE date = " + 
                                    date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +
                                    " AND measured_dist = bit_loc AND rop > 0")
```

My problem is that it produces a string that looks like:

```
SELECT timestamp FROM hdd_local_data_v1_2 WHERE date = 2012-08-21 AND measured_dist = bit_loc AND rop > 0
```

Running this query in SQLite, I end up with 0 results.  However, if I run:

```
// Quotes around the date
SELECT timestamp FROM hdd_local_data_v1_2 WHERE date = "2012-08-21" AND measured_dist = bit_loc AND rop > 0
```

I get the results that I'm expecting.  I realize that I can get the results that I'm expecting by using:

```
connection.Query("SELECT timestamp FROM hdd_local_data_v1_2 WHERE date = \"" + 
                                   date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + 
                                   "\" AND measured_dist = bit_loc AND rop > 0")
```

My question is, is it possible to get the expected query without using the escape `\`?  And to an even greater degree, is there a way to use LINQ to query the database once a connection has been made?

Comment: your code is prone to "SQL injection" which is a serious security problem! using parameterized queries is the way to go and implemented correctly you don't need the quotes... LINQ would would work too...

Comment: You can use linq to sql the best resouce of examples I have found are listed below http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085.aspx